# Angular2: registration form valitation

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular2 with bootstrap3.

I need to make a registration form with 3 fields:

- Mail
- Password
- Confirmation password

I need to check:

1. mail is well formed.
2. mail is not registered yet (I need to check it on server).
3. password field and password-confirmation field are the same.

I've tried to find it out how to get it, but I've not able to figure out what do I need to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are tons of tutorial on this subject on the internet. Just google...
I recommend to read [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use angular2 form validations for validating string and numbers. we can check maximum length, minimum length , the pattern in a string and min and max of numbers easily. here is an example for that (https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation). you can use `*ngIf` and `[(ngModel)]` to check password and its confirmation are same. :) cheers. and enjoy angular 2 :D